# Multiple wsdl:part elements in input message of SOAP operation

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I am trying to rewrite existing service from Axis 1 to Spring WS. I have been looking at a lot of examples and simple tutorials but none of them uses multiple parts in input message of SOAP operation.

Does Spring WS allow binding multiple `wsdl:part`s to a function parameters in `@Endpoint` class? If it does, how?

My input message looks like this:

```
<wsdl:message name="getMetricDataRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="agent" type="xsd:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="metric" type="xsd:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="startTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
    <wsdl:part name="endTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
</wsdl:message>
```